# Bought a @font-face, not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts, font-face

My client bought a font to be used. This is the code generated for it:

```
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/27ec77");

@font-face {font-family: 'FranklinGothicURWCon-Boo';
    src: url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_0_0.eot');
    src: url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
    url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}

@font-face {font-family: 'FranklinGothicURWCon-Dem';
    src: url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_1_0.eot');
        src: url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_1_0.woff') format('woff'),
        url('www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/styles/webfonts/27EC77_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

This works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer. See here:
http://www.mybariatricsolutionsseminars.com/new/

Some solutions I've tried:

1. Added this code to .htaccess. (This didn't work.)

   ```
   AddType font/ttf .ttf
   AddType font/eot .eot
   AddType font/otf .otf
   AddType font/woff .woff

   <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
       <IfModule mod_headers.c>
           Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
       </IfModule>
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
2. Add `http://` on src URLs. (This also didn't work.)

Comment: Add the http:// in front of the www. Also, it doesn't work in Chrome, you probably have the font installed locally.

Comment: Hi I double checked it and the font didn't work on Chrome when I removed the @font-face code above. I've also added http:// on all of them but no luck still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mimetypes aren't set up correctly.

Looking in the Chrome Dev Tools shows lots of:

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Assuming you are using apache with .htaccess files, add:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff
```

to the .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi I've added this code. Still the fonts aren't loading. Good news it it now works on IE9 and IE10. Thanks the only problem now is it's still not loading on Firefox.

Comment: Ok.. for some unknown reasons the font didn't load again in IE.